# Finding the closest intersecting triangle in Open3D between a triangle mesh and a voxel grid

Tags: python, open3d

I'm currently working with a triangle mesh and a voxel grid using Open3D in Python. My goal is to find the triangle that intersects a given voxel and is closest to the voxel center.

I tried using a kdtree with the mesh. Here's the Python code using kdtree with a MWE:

```py
import open3d as o3d
import numpy as np

vertices = np.array([[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]])
triangles = np.array([[0, 1, 2]])
mesh = o3d.geometry.TriangleMesh()
mesh.vertices = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(vertices)
mesh.triangles = o3d.utility.Vector3iVector(triangles)

# Sample query points, to be replaced by voxel centers
voxel_centers = np.array([[0.1, 0.1, 0.1], [0.5, 0.5, 0.5], [0.9, 0.9, 0.9]])

# Create a KDTree for efficient nearest neighbor search
kdtree = o3d.geometry.KDTreeFlann(mesh)
closest_triangles= []
for voxel_center in voxel_centers:
    # Search for the closest point on the mesh surface to the voxel center
    _, triangle_id, _ = kdtree.search_knn_vector_3d(voxel_center, 1)
    closest_triangles.append(triangle_id[0])

closest_triangles = np.array(closest_triangles)

print("Closest triangles")
print(closest_triangles)
```

The output is

```
Closest triangles
[0 0 1]
```

even though there is only one triangle! While this returns the indices of the closest **vertices**, I'm struggling to find indices of closest **triangles**.

I appreciate any advice on correctly converting the indices obtained from the kdtree into the corresponding triangles or any alternative approaches to finding the closest intersecting triangle efficiently.

Thanks in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

In Open3D, kdtree is constructed not using the triangles but using the vertices of the geometry you provide. Check the source code [here](https://github.com/isl-org/Open3D/blob/main/cpp/open3d/geometry/KDTreeFlann.cpp#L51).

The KDTree is generated using mesh vertices. So for each of your query point, you get the nearest vertex index, not the nearest triangle index. Note, the vertex doesnt have to be part of a Triangle.

Comment: To find if your mesh is intersecting with a voxel in voxel grid, one solution can be to generate a `RayCastingScene` and check for zero crossing on voxel corners. However, this is not accurate if voxel has large size and then you can have a mesh which carves voxel along a face but never crosses a vertex. Think a ball protruding on center of one face of voxel. Here all corner vertex are outside the mesh, so no zero crossing but the mesh do intersects. In this scenario, keeping voxel size small will help. https://www.open3d.org/docs/release/tutorial/geometry/distance_queries.html

Comment: Is there a better way to estimate normals on a regular lattice? I thought I would create a voxel-grid, find the closest intersecting triangle for every voxel-center and find the normal of that triangle.